# Entity model adds "s" at the end of table names

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model

When I create Entity Model in my ASP.NET application it adds "s" at the end of each entity name, i.e. if my table name is "SiteUser" in database it becomes "SiteUsers" in Entity Model. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your EDMX file, click on an empty space in your designer view and in the properties window set `Pluralize New Objects` to `False`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the properties of your entity model, than you will find the property "Pluralize new objects", set it to false to stop adding the s to your new added objects.